# Hide parent if all li children element have CSS style display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children

I'm not able to do it 'cause the `li` blocks are many on the page...

simplified HTML:

```
    <li class="first"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">AUDIO</a>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="  toto"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Audio one</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="  toto"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Accessories (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
        <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Audio mp3 (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
        <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Audio player (<font color="#0b8553"><b>1</b></font>)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Audio hifi</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="last  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">Audio items (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="first"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">OTHER</a>
  <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 2</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 3 (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
        <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 4 (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
        <li class="  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 5 (<font color="#0b8553"><b>1</b></font>)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 6</a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li class="last  toto" style="display:none"> <a href="http://myweb.com/test/something" title="">other 7 (<font color="#0b8553"><b>0</b></font>)</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

as you can see the first block has some **`<li class="  toto">`** without css display none, while the second block (OTHER) has all the li with **style="display:none"**

so, I need to hide that specific **.first** ONLY with jQuery... and again, there are many blocks like that on the page.

eg.

```
if(!$(".first").children().is(':visible')) {
  $(".first").hide();
}
```

this doesn't work 'cause it selects all the .first on the page, I need to check that for each .first individually and hide or keep it....

The final result in this case must be:

**AUDIO** (without "OTHER")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would just filter the `li.first` elements based on whether the total number of `li` descendant elements equals the number selected with `li:hidden`.

```
$('li.first').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('li').length === $(this).find('li:hidden').length;
}).hide();
```

However, that clearly won't work in your case because technically all the descendant `li` elements are hidden in your HTML because their parent `ul` element is also hidden.

If you want to check based on the `display` property of each `li` element, then you can use:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/10v97jn9/)

```
$('li.first').filter(function () {
  return $(this).find('li').length === $(this).find('li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('display') === 'none';
  }).length;
}).hide();
```